How to get around mouse entry signal stopping at first collision?
I have a grid of Area3D objects, and when nothing is around them, they handle the mouse_entered signal exactly as I would expect. The only issue is that I also use Area3D's on other game objects, like enemies, and when they walk in front of the grid, their collider seems to "block" the mouse from being able to enter the grid colliders. I.e., the grid will recognize the mouse entry until the enemy collider overlaps, and suddenly, I am unable to trigger the collider in the overlaping space, and once the enemy leaves it works perfectly again. I am assuming that there is something like a mouse raycast going on behind the scenes, but it stops at the first collider it hits?
I tried changing the collision layer and mask, but this didnt seem to fix the issue. Is there some other way of ensuring that the mouse is able to get into the collider and emit the signal at all times?

Set input_ray_pickable to false on the physic bodies or areas that you do not want to take mouse input.
